# Rolling Echo's size after an AP?

Tags: dnd-4e, bard

See the Voice of Thunder PP [here](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/mobile/display.aspx?page=ParagonPath&id=264).

Rolling Echo allows you to repeat the attack the following round. If you use an AP to make the Rolling Echo attack, it goes from Close Burst 2 to Close Burst 3.

When you repeat the attack, is it a Close Burst 3 again, or does it go back to being a CB2? I.e. does repeating the attack mean it gets the same modifiers?

A related question, although it may have a different answer: After making the Rolling Echo attack, the Voice of Thunder is disarmed. At the start of the VoT's next turn, does the Rolling Echo repeat with the original modifiers of that implement, or does the repeat occur without the implement (and is therefore less powerful)?

Comment: Good first question, though you'd be better off splitting the second part, about VoT into a separate question altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rolling Echo returns to its normal size.**

The phrasing here is a little finicky.

The AP feature for the PP says (*emphasis mine*):

> **Voice of Thunder:** When you spend an action point to take an extra action, the size of any close burst attack you make *during that action* increases by 1, and the size of any close blast attack you make *during that action* increases by 2.

The Rolling Echo power itself says (*emphasis mine*):

> **Hit:** 2d6 + Charisma modifier thunder damage, and you push the target 1 square. Before you take any actions during your next turn, you can repeat the attack *as a free action*.

So the AP feature lets you expand the size of any blast or burst attack you use the extra action from an AP to make. Rolling Echo's repeated attack is made using a free action, and thus is *not* made using the action from an AP; therefore it does **not** receive the increased size from the AP feature.

*Related Question*

This is a little more open to interpretation. Because it merely says "repeat the attack", and doesn't mention bonuses/penalties/modifiers, I would say that you make the attack again but recalculate your attack bonus & damage bonus at the time you make the repeat attack. As a DM, I would personally houserule it to recalculate those things anyway, to prevent the stacking of bonuses (resourceful presence + Flexible Authority, for example).

Comment: Agreed, the during that action is what locks it up to only being during the original AP. Now if you had more than one AP from milestones....

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith You mean more than one AP *and* the ability to spend more than one AP per encounter, right?

Comment: And even if you could spend a 2nd AP, it wouldn't affect the free action, as it only affects the attacks during that action.

Comment: @ObliviousSage lol yes and my forgetting that important rule.